# Python sliding MinMaxScaler on last 100 values

Tags: python, pandas

I now have a normalization across the entire column:

```
MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(Glfeatures[['Temp']])
```

How to get a column without for, where for each value is normalized to 100 values to it?

For example:

```
Glfeatures['Temp'][200] minmaxnormalizing on Glfeatures['Temp'][100:200]
Glfeatures['Temp'][300] minmaxnormalizing on Glfeatures['Temp'][200:300]
```

I need fast version :) normalization for all Glfeatures on last 100 values.

I tried `Glres[['Temp']].rolling(100).apply(MinMaxScaler())` but: "'MinMaxScaler' object is not callable"

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index//100)...`?

Comment: @Henry Yik This is a grouping with a step of 100. I need to MINMAX normalize each value in a column relative to the previous 100 values

Comment: Then use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html).

Comment: @Henry Yik, I try    Glres[['Temp']].rolling(100).apply(MinMaxScaler())    But "TypeError: 'MinMaxScaler' object is not callable"

Comment: `MinMaxScaler().fit_transform` is the class method that actually does the scaling. Or use this [separate function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale) But I doubt it'll be very fast when applied in a rolling window.

Comment: @Swier I tries 'MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(Glfeatures[['Temp']])' but this work for all data, i need rolling 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but I stumbled across it trying to accomplish the same thing.

Here is my solution as suggested in the comments above:

```
def min_max(df, window):

    def func(data):
    
        x = data.values
            
        return (x[-1] - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))

    return df.rolling(window).apply(func)
```

The code snippet applies the min max scaling to the previous `window` values per column in the dataframe `df`